# Nginx index.html is override With Shared Volume

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, volumes

I have a Pod with an **emptyDir** volume mounted in two containers:

- nginx at **/usr/share/nginx/html/**
- busybox at **/var/html/**

If i create a file with html extension inside **busybox container** at **/var/html** this file is **copied** to **nginx container** in **/usr/share/nginx/html** and i cant figure out why this happens.

The same behavior happens in this documentation example:
https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/communicate-containers-same-pod-shared-volume/

Pod Manifest:

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: web-server
  labels:
    book: kubernetes-in-action
    section: 6-2-1-Using-an-emptyDir-volume
spec:
  containers:
    - image: nginx
      name: web-server
      volumeMounts:
        - name: html-vol
          mountPath: /usr/share/nginx/html
    - image: busybox
      name: content-agent
      command: ["/bin/sh", "-c"]
      args: ["\
              echo \"$(date) | creating html file at var/html\"; \
              echo \"<h1> $(date) </h1>\" > var/html/front.html; \
              sleep 15; \
              while true; do \
                echo \"$(date) | append to html file at var/html\"; \
                echo \"<h1> $(date) </h1>\" >> var/html/front.html; \
                sleep 15; \
              done; \
            "]
      volumeMounts:
        - name: html-vol
          mountPath: /var/html
  volumes:
    - name: html-vol
      emptyDir: {}
```

Comment: It's not "copied" _per se_; it is literally the same file (the mounted `emptyDir` volume) in both containers.  What behavior are you expecting?

Comment: Is the same volume with different mount paths so i thought the file written in /var/html not affect the /usr/share/nginx/html directory

Comment: i found some info, this setup behaves like a bind mount in linux. https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/198590/what-is-a-bind-mount